# Visual Studio Express: registration issue

Tags: visual-studio-express

I have downloaded and been using Visual Studio Express for last few weeks. All of a sudden today, it's forcing me to register. When I try to do so, the registration site appears to be unresponsive. This is horrible, and now I can not continue with my work because of Microsoft's broken site.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Yes... I click the registration button on visual studio 2008 express edition registration dialog box

Comment: @dotnet-practitioner, you should accept George's answer if it resolved your issue, if not then if you edit your question and add some additional information

Answer (score 3):

The easiest thing to do is download the offline installer and install that. If you do it this way, you don't have to register at all. You can find the offline installer at http://www.microsoft.com/express/download/default.aspx#download-offline

Comment: As an aside, I've never needed to register my express installations, I've always clicked the "Do not register" checkbox and moved on with my life

Comment: This does not work for `Visual Studio 2010`. I used the offline installer and am still prompted to register. Microsoft confirms this on their blog support forum.

Comment: The link to the offline installer does not work anymore.